# Printing out two variables on one line?

Tags: java

I can't seem to figure out how to print both variables `i` and `balance`. When i use `+` it actually adds them. I also tried several other ways to do it that I looked up on Google but they didn't come out correct either. However When I print out either variable `i` or `balance` by themselves, I do get the correct result. Can someone help me?

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Forloops
{
    public static void main (String [ ] args)
    {
        System.out.print("Enter Balance:");
        double balance = input.nextDouble();

        System.out.print("Enter Number of Months:");
        int i = input.nextInt();

        for ( i = 0; i <= 12; i = i + 1 ) 
        {
            balance = balance * (1.00417);
            System.out.println( balance);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
System.out.println(String.valueOf(i) + String.valueOf(balance))
```

Comment: Your answer is better than mine was. :)

Comment: yeah this worked bro, I didn't know those commands but thank you :) it was starting to get frustrating

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively

```
System.out.println(i + "" + balance);
```

or

```
System.out.println("After " + i +" months: " + balance);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
System.out.println("I = " + i + " balance = " + balance);
```

Comment: i tried this one before but it didn't come out right..Idk why but when i copied and pasted this one it worked, thank you too

Answer (score 0):

When you have a `string` and sum it with an `integer`, Java will cast the `integer` to `string` automatically. The problem is that you aren't using any string inside the `println()` function. So the basic thing is to add `""` between `i` and `balance`.

```
System.out.println(i + "" + balance);
```

This would work fine, but you have to know why. If `balance` was a `string`, using the way you thought would work, don't forget this, **java will cast the variable when needed**, when you should've done, like adding two different type of variables.